# Unable to drop DataFrame rows using dropna method by describing acceptable threshold of NaN (null) count

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I intend to drop records from a DataFrame, using dropna method, along axis=0 (rows) with more than 25% values as NaN. I have reviewed the official Pandas reference and come up with the below code. However, this is not giving the intended result. What am I missing?

Also, to make the issue reproducible sharing the data file.

**References reviewed:**

1. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html
2. Multitude of existing stackoverflow posts on somewhat related topic.

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data3.csv')

# Method that doesn't work
df.shape # (628, 123)
df.dropna(thresh=df.shape[1]/ 4, axis=0, inplace=True)
#OR --- df.dropna(thresh=df.shape[1]/ 4, axis=0, subset=list(df.columns), inplace=True)
df.shape # (628, 123)

# Method that works
df.shape # (628, 123)
df = df[(df.isna().sum(axis=1) < df.shape[1]/ 4)]
df.shape # (626, 123)
```

**CSV File Link:** https://wetransfer.com/downloads/57e63e83bd6b62ca8016768bec732f7720201127140326/2a946b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your rows have at least `df.shape[1]/ 4 = 30.7` non-NaN values that's why your `drop` statement does not work -- nothing to drop there. It sounds like you want the number of *non-NaNs* to be *at least* `df.shape[1] - df.shape[1]/ 4`, judging by your operation that does work for you. So this

```
df.dropna(thresh = df.shape[1] - df.shape[1]/ 4, axis=0).shape
```

produces

```
(626, 123)
```

as you would want

Comment: Thanks for providing a detailed explanation. I misinterpreted the thresh parameter. All this while I was expecting it to be the number of NaN values beyond which a record should be dropped.